# Empty Datatable cells using JSF2 Primefaces 6

Tags: primefaces, datatable, jsf-2, java-ee-8

I have an application loading a datatable from a backing bean. The **SubAreas** datatable loads the correct number of rows, however they are empty as seen on the image. After debuging I can see that **listaArea** atribute on the backing bean(responsible for populating the table) is getting the correct data from the database. **Area** is the entity.

[image: Empty DataTable]

Another datatable on the same screen, called **Membros** works without a problem.

[image: Functioning Datatable]

### AREA.XHTML

```
  <div>
    <fieldset style="display:#{(areaMB.state == 'update')?'block':'none'}">
      <p:dataTable var="teste" id="dtTeste" value="#{areaMB.listaArea}" 
                   widgetVar="dtArea" paginator="true" 
                   paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}" 
                   rowsPerPageTemplate="20, 50, 100"
                   rows="20" rowKey="#{area.idArea}" 
                   emptyMessage="Nenhum registro" paginatorPosition="bottom">

        <p:column headerText="#" width="10%">
          <h:outputText value="#{area.idArea}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Descrição" width="40%" 
                  filterBy="#{area.descricao}" 
                  filterMatchMode="contains">
          <h:outputText value="#{area.descricao}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Sigla" width="20%">
          <h:outputText value="#{area.sigla}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Ativo" width="20%">
          <h:outputText value="ATIVO" rendered="#{area.flgAtivo==1}" />
          <h:outputText value="INATIVO" rendered="#{area.flgAtivo==0}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="" width="10%" style="text-align:center">
          <p:commandButton action="#{areaMB.preparaAlterar}" 
                           update=":formu" 
                           icon="fa fa-pencil" style="margin-right:10px" 
                           title="Alterar" 
                           styleClass="btn btn-default btn-xs">
            <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{areaMB.area}" value="#{area}" />
          </p:commandButton>
        </p:column>
      </p:dataTable>

    </fieldset>
  </div>
</h:panelGroup>
```

### MANAGED BEAN

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class AreaMB implements Serializable {

    private String state = "search";
    private String descricao;
    private Area area = new Area();
    private Area subArea = new Area();
    private Usuario usuario = new Usuario();
    private AreaUsuario areaUsuario = new AreaUsuario();
    private List<Usuario> listaUsuario;
    private List<Area> listaArea;
    private List<AreaUsuario> listaAreaUsuario;
    private List<SelectItem> listaMembro;
    private List<Area> listaSubAreas;
    private List<TipoArea> listaTipoArea;
    private List<Area> listaAreaVinculada;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() throws Exception {
        pesquisar();

    }

public void pesquisar() {
        try {
            listaArea = AreaService.getInstancia().pesquisar(area, 0, 0);
            listaTipoArea = TipoAreaService.getInstancia().getAll();

            //a area vinculada nao pode ser ela mesma
            listaAreaVinculada = AreaService.getInstancia().getAll();
            if (listaAreaVinculada.contains(area)) {
                listaAreaVinculada.remove(area);  
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
    }

public void preparaAlterar() {
    try {
        state = "update";

        AreaUsuario au = new AreaUsuario();
        au.setIdArea(area.getIdArea());

        listaAreaUsuario = AreaUsuarioService.getInstancia().pesquisar(au, AreaUsuarioService.JOIN_USUARIO, 0);
        listaMembro = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
        for (AreaUsuario aUsuario : listaAreaUsuario) {
            listaMembro.add(new SelectItem(aUsuario.getIdUsuario(), aUsuario.getUsuario().getNome()));
        }

        listaAreaVinculada.remove(area);  
        listaSubAreas = AreaService.getInstancia().getSubAreas(area);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());
    }

}
```

Why is it bringing empty cells?

Comment: Replace `var="teste"` with `var="area"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The var of your dateTable is called  teste  (`var="teste"`), while the var used in values and rendered in your `h:outputText` are `area`.

You can change to `var="area"`, or change all the values and rendered of the `h:outputText` to `"#{teste.XXX}"`

Comment: I can't believe i didn't see that!